# I need help positioning datepicker in shopify

Tags: jquery, datepicker, shopify

I am working on a Shopify website and I am putting a Datepicker on the cart screen by creating a snippet with the code below. I then added this snippet to my cart template and it seems to work well. Now I have the issue that it is off to the right of the screen and i want it centered and also make it mandatory before clicking the checkout button. I have seen a lot of solutions to being centered, but I have no idea where I'm supposed to put the code to fix it. In the snippet or in the template that asks for the snippet?:

```
{{ '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' | stylesheet_tag }}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" defer="defer"></script>

  <div style="width:300px; clear:both;">
</div>
    <p>
      <label for="date">Pick a delivery or pickup date:</label>
      <input id="date" type="text" name="attributes[date]" value="{{ cart.attributes.date }}" />
      <span style="display:block" class="instructions"> Your preferred disclaimers here. </span>
    </p>
  </div>

  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      if (window.jQuery) {
        let $ = window.jQuery;

        $(function() {
          $("#date").datepicker({
            minDate: +1,
            maxDate: '+2M',
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
          });
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
<div id="datepicker-container">
  <div id="datepicker-center">
    <div id="datepicker"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I put in the template section to call on the snippet.

```
{% render 'delivery-date' %}
```

Any help would be fantastic as I've read every post I can find but cant get this to work and I'm ready to pull my hair out :)

Please forgive me if I'm not following proper etiquette as this is only my first or second post.
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, ID have to be unique

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Can you be more specific on what I need to do to center it on the screen?

Comment: I just realized I had accidentally pasted the end of the code twice. I corrected it above.